# AKKA - How can I unit test my actor that handle a TCP connection?

Tags: java, tcp, akka

I have an actor that binds a port a the preStart and then expect the Tcp.Bound message. Then, it will just wait for a Tcp.Connected to happen. This actor does not provides anything to its creator so I would like to receive the Tcp Message and/or mock the Tcp Manager

So far I tried to subscribe my TestKit Probe to the tcp messages. Other than that I am looking to create a class that would override the manager, but still don't know how to do it. I am using Java 8 and JUnit 5.

```
@Override
    public void preStart() {
         this.connection = Tcp.get(getContext().getSystem()).manager();
         this.connection.tell(TcpMessage.bind(getSelf(), remoteAddress, 100), getSelf());
    }

 @Override
    public AbstractActor.Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(Tcp.Bound.class, msg -> {
                    log.debug("Port Bound : [{}]", msg.localAddress());
                    this.sessionHandler = getContext().actorOf(RmiSessionHandler.props(getSelf(), settings));
                    this.buffer = getContext().actorOf(RmiBuffer.props(this.sessionHandler, settings));
                    this.connection = getSender();

                }).match(Tcp.Connected.class, msg -> {
                    log.debug("Port Connected to : [{}])", msg.remoteAddress());
                    this.sessionHandler.tell(msg, getSelf());
                    sender().tell(TcpMessage.register(getSelf()), getSelf()); // Register ourselves
                    this.session = getSender();
                    this.isConnectedToClient = true;
```

You can see that my actor just creates other actors, but I don't want to go through them to test that he established the connection.

Would really like to know when my actor is sending Tcp.Bind or when a port is bound and on which port.

Here is what I've tried :

```
system = ActorSystem.create("sessionHandlerTest");
testProbe = new TestKit(system);
system.eventStream().subscribe(testProbe.getRef(), Tcp.Bound.class);
rmiSocket = system.actorOf(RmiSocket.props(testProbe.getRef(), settings));
Tcp.Bound bindingMessage = testProbe.expectMsgClass(Tcp.Bound.class);
```

Also I tried to register my probe to the tcp manager :

```
ActorRef tcpManager = Tcp.get(system).manager();
tcpManager.tell(TcpMessage.register(testProbe.getRef()), testProbe.getRef());
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in short let's assume you have a class A that needs to connect to a database. Instead of letting A actually connect, you provide A with an interface that A may use to connect. For testing you implement this interface with some stuff - without connecting of course. If class B instantiates A it has to pass a "real" database connection to A. But that means B opens a database connection. That means to test B you inject the connection into B. But B is instantiated in class C and so forth.

So at which point do I have to say "here I fetch data from a database and I will not write a unit test for this piece of code"?

In other words: Somewhere in the code in some class I must call sqlDB.connect() or something similar. How do I test this class?

And is it the same with code that has to deal with a GUI or a file system?

Comment: If I understand your point of view, you are saying that because I don't interact with the creator of my actor I shouldn't test the tcp connection that it is doing? 

I understand the point where a gui doesn't really need or is extremely difficult to unit test, but in this case the steps toward the tcp connection are very important for my software. I need to verify that at no point we change the order depending of the state.

Also, I don't want to test through the subsequent actors because they also have other critical roles and multiple states the won't really represent the tcp connection.

Comment: Also, this actor is the only one dealing with the tcp connection. No other classes or actors will deal with the connection. This actor is getting the tcp manager, initiate the binding and manage the connection all by itself.